# How to fix distorted thumb images retrieved with AVAssetImageGenerator?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avasset

The camera roll in the Camera app is showing the correct aspect ratio for the images.

When I retrieve thumbs with AVAssetImageGenerator some thumbs look very distorted. Like 10 times longer than heigh. Always the same images look distorted while others look correct. All images taken with Camera app. Inside camera roll of Camera app, all images look correct. Also the ones that are distorted with AVAssetImageGenerator.

I retrieve the thumbs like this:

```
if (!_imageGenerator) {
        self.imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:self.avAsset];

        _imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    }
    _imageGenerator.maximumSize = maxSize;

    [_imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:kCMTimeZero]]
                                         completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime,
                                                             CGImageRef image,
                                                             CMTime actualTime,
                                                             AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result,
                                                             NSError *error) {

                                                 if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {

                                                     weakSelf.thumbImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
                                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                         NSLog(@"Loaded thumbnail");
                                                         completionHandler(weakSelf.thumbImage);
                                                     });
                                                 }
                                                 else if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorFailed) {
                                                     // retry
                                                 }
                                     }];
```

Tested with iOS 7 on iPhone 5. Also tested other times than zero. Same videos always delivers distorted thumbs while others are ok. What can be the problem or is there a workaround?